# Call a callback function after rendering the anchor in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've the following HTML in my layout:

```
<div class="icon-grid">

<a ng-if="udtTable.config.moreActionIcons" ng-repeat="mai in udtTable.config.moreActionIcons" 
ng-attr-data-toggle="{{(mai.modal) ? \'modal\' : undefined}}" 
ng-attr-data-target="{{(mai.modalName && mai.modal) ? mai.modalName : undefined}}"  
after-render="{{mai.callback}}"
href="{{mai.action}}/{{value.data.id}}" 
title="{{mai.tooltip}}">

<span class="{{mai.icon}}"></span>

</a>

</div>
```

Here is my `after-render` directive:

```
angular.module('neogetDataTableServices').directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.afterRender);
        }
    };
    return def;
}]);
```

Here is my object to repeat

```
var udtTable = {
  config: {
     "moreActionIcons" : [
            {
                "action": 'myaction.php',
                "icon": "icomoon-lock-open",
                "modal": true,
                "modalName": "#mkjax-modal",
                "tooltip":"Authorize",
                "callback": function() {
                    alert('hey rendered');
                }
            },
     ]
  }
}
```

Now the problem is if I write this line

```
after-render="helloworld"
```

Then my directive `after-render` logs it properly through `console.log(attrs.afterRender);`

**But if I write this like below:**

```
after-render="{{mai.callback}}"
```

Then the directive doesn't logs `function() { alert('hey rendered'); }` It says that it is an empty string.

Anybody has the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
angular.module('neogetDataTableServices').directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.afterRender);
        }
    };
    return def;
}]);
```

In html:

```
after-render="mai.callback()"
```

Comment: console.log(element) logs the element object but how to make it visible?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com it must be css issue, use F12 chrome inspector

Comment: No, if I remove after-render attribute, then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use an isolated `scope`.

```
angular.module('neogetDataTableServices').directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
var def = {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    transclude: false,
    scope:{
      afterRender:"&"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.afterRender);
    }
};
return def;}]);
```

In this case, angular will interpret attribute as a function.

in html

```
after-render="mai.callback()"
```

Comment: You can provide `jsFiddle`? It may not work, because in isolated `scope` you do not get attributes `ng-attr-data-toggle` and `ng-attr-data-target`.